# Edit component for sub-routed nested resource

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying to use custom routes for nested resources.
**Request** is a "real" resource as table on db whereas **Participants** is a "virtual" resource, it refers to **request_details** table.

I have the following:

```
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="requests" list={RequestsList} create={NewRequest} edit={EditRequest} >
        <Route path=":reqID/participants" element={<ReqParticipantsList />} />
        <Route path=":reqID/participant/:partID" element={<ReqParticipantsEdit />} />
    </Resource>
</Admin>
```

When I go to /requests/11/participants the following code is loaded for **ReqParticipantsList** component and all is ok:

```
<ListBase resource="request_details">
```

but when I go to /requests/11/participant/205 and the code of **ReqParticipantsEdit** component contains

```
<EditBase resource="request_details">
```

I'm redirected to /request_details with an error (obviously).

In the **ReqParticipantsEdit** component I tried to use Edit, EditBase, ResourceContextProvider but nothing seems to work. If I use the simple paragraph to "log"

```
<p>{`Request ID: ${reqID}, Participant ID: ${partID}`}</p>
```

the 2 values are returned correctly (reqID and partID)

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly I think you want:

```
<ListBase resource="participants">
```

and

```
<EditBase resource="participants">
```